# BroadcastReceiver, one activity over, won't receive message

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have the activity SingleSpecial where a user clicks to share and initiates the actions below:

```
    inviteFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Send broadcast of the sharedId to the SharingAction
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.example.specialSharing.SHARED_SPECIAL");
            i.putExtra("specialId", specialId);
            sendBroadcast(i);

            // Open invite activity:
            Intent specialSharing = new Intent(getBaseContext(), InviteFriendOrGroup.class);
            startActivity(specialSharing);
        }
     }
```

The InviteFriendOrGroup.class is intended to open and the user selects a person to share with. Upon selecting the person to share, the `SharingAction` class will open and is supposed to accept the Broadcast from the activity two steps ago, from the SingleSpecial class.

I have setup the Broadcast receiver to accept the action, and setup in the onCreate method of SharingAction:

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class SpecialInfoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.i("Shared special received ", "received special id");
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            if (extra != null) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals("com.example.specialSharing.SHARED_SPECIAL")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The shared special Id is ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

receiver in the onCreate:

```
SpecialInfoReceiver specialInfoReceiver = new SpecialInfoReceiver();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.specialSharing.SHARED_SPECIAL");
        this.registerReceiver(specialInfoReceiver, filter);
```

As can be seen, the receiver is to show a toast upon receiving the sepcialId action. But it does nothing.

How can I set this up to work?

Answer (score 0):

As per android documentation for the constructor for Intent(String action):

> Create an intent with a given action. All other fields (data, type, class) are null. Note that the action must be in a namespace because Intents are used globally in the system -- for example the system VIEW action is android.intent.action.VIEW; an application's custom action would be something like com.google.app.myapp.CUSTOM_ACTION.

As well as Intent.setAction()'s action parameter:

> An action name, such as ACTION_VIEW. Application-specific actions should be prefixed with the vendor's package name.

Both suggest valid action names are ones that belong within your namespace (base package). Not prefixing the namespace can lead to widespread problems of clashing action names between different apps.

It is possible the broadcast was never successfully made due to an invalid action name. Try changing the action to `<package>.SHARED_SPECIAL`.

Consider using a LocalBroadcastManager if you only intend to send broadcasts within your application. It is safer (as in other app components won't suddenly trigger if they were listening on the Intent).

Comment: I changed the action to `com.example.specialSharing.SHARED_SPECIAL` and removed the specialId variable, but still nothing...see updated code

Comment: Could it be that the intermittent action is preventing the broadcast from being received? How can I send data without opening the activity?

Comment: Never mind, I used sharedPreferences instead, much less troublsome

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Broadcast to the Manifest?

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.SpecialInfoReceiver"/>
```

Or if Broadcast is inside another class:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.YourActivity.$SpecialInfoReceiver"/>
```